# quiver 3d vector plot color error (arrows appears with strange two colors)

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector, colors, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to plot a 3d vectorplot with different color for some vectors. Could there be a bug in quiver or am I blind :-)  ?
Some arrows appears with strange "two color look".

[image]

I could break down the code to following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pandas as pd

X = [39.954,39.932,39.91,39.914,39.915]
Y = [60.52,54.904,56.16,55.436,55.628]
Z = [39.1,42.5,42.7,43.0,43.5]
U = [5.704,7.507,9.526,8.095,6.762]
V = [13.896,-4.116,3.959,-0.627,0.22]
W = [-3.43,40.474,35.515,34.182,30.944]
Plot_Farbe = ['black', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red']
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, U, V, W, colors = Plot_Farbe,length=0.2)
ax.set_xlim([35, 45])
ax.set_ylim([50, 65])
ax.set_zlim([35, 55])
plt.show()
```

I have tried this under

- Python: 3.10.11
- matplotlib: 3.7.1
- Windows 11
- Ubuntu

I would be glad for a solution where each arrow has **one** color. In the end there will be a function for setting colors and several hundred vectors.